# Assigning single value select output from stored procedure to a variable (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure GetNumberbyUniversalIDandGroup which 2 input paramters and returns the results of a SELECT query. This query has one row and one column (i.e. a single value). How can I assign this to a variable in a calling stored procedure?

Can I work with the result of the stored procedure. For example the following doesn't appear to work:

select * from (exec GetNumberbyUniversalIDandGroup '0032409901',1723817)

Comment: Change it from being a stored procedure to being a scalar UDF?

Comment: It's an existing stored procedure that is used elsewhere so I cannot change it and would like to work with it rather than having to create something new

Comment: But there's no easy way to compose stored procedures inside of queries. They're not designed for it. You can create the scalar UDF with a new name and then just make the existing stored procedure a trivial wrapper that calls the UDF - that way you don't end up with duplicated code, at least, and existing callers are unaffected.

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good idea. As an aside is there a way that I can come up with an alternative solution by making use of a cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure must have a Return keyword, and then the code will be like:

```
 create proc myproc
 as 
 begin
     return 1
 end
 go
 declare @i int
 exec @i = myproc
```

or if you want to keep your stored procedure as it is, you can use temporary table:

```
Insert Into #TempTable
Exec myproc
```

Comment: I don't want to alter the GetNumberbyUniversalIDandGroup stored procedure as it is being used by other code. Is it possible to have both a return and a SELECT query that are both returned?

Comment: You can use temporary table, i add it to my answer